# Subtract unsigned and get signed

Tags: c++, c

Can I make a cast in this way?

```
int clockOffset;

clockOffset=((int64_t)Time_1_delayed-Time_1-Time_2_delayed+Time_2)/2;
```

where all the Time variables are `uint`.

I want to have the signed result in `clockOffset`.

Comment: the only value you're casting in there is time_1_delayed. you'd have to cast each individual value.

Comment: @MarcB Why? The cast would "propagate" to other summands because of the default conversions.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze No. At least not in C, not sure about C++. In C, operation on a signed and an unsigned integer results in an unsigned value.

Comment: @MarcB yes it works, but what hapens if the MSB of Time_1 is 1 ?

Comment: @H2CO3 `((int64_t)Time_1_delayed-Time_1-Time_2_delayed+Time_2)/2` is going to be grouped as `((((int64_t)Time_1_delayed-Time_1)-Time_2_delayed)+Time_2)/2`. `Time_1` will get converted to `int64_t` in the first subtraction and the result of this subtraction will be of type `int64_t`. This will continue happening until the end of the expression.

Comment: @H2CO3 It is not simply “unsigned trumps signed”. The rule actually is (e.g. C99 6.3.1.8:1) “if the operand that has unsigned integer type **has rank greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand**, then the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.” The emphasis is mine, and that clause can be assumed not to be true here with unsigned `uint` and signed `int64_t` (although it could be true with a compiler with 64-bit `int` depending on the exact typedefs for `uint` and `int64_t`)

Comment: @PascalCuoq Thank you. That was helpful. I once read that it was indeed "unsigned pwns signed" - silly me, I trusted the source and didn't read the Standard.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do in C (assuming ints and unsigned ints are shorter than long longs):

```
#include <limits.h>

...
  unsigned int Time_1_delayed, Time_1, Time_2_delayed, Time_2;
...
  long long diff = ((long long)Time_1_delayed - Time_1 - Time_2_delayed + Time_2) / 2;
  int clockOffset;

  if (diff < INT_MIN || diff > INT_MAX)
    HandleTheError();

  clockOffset = diff;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cast. For example you can do.

```
uint32_t a = 100;
uint32_t b = 200;
int32_t c = a - b;
```

And you'll get `c = -100`.